# Are any bonuses added when using Vital Strike in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

For the Vital Strike feat in Pathfinder, are other bonuses such as enhancement or sacred bonuses to damage applied when rolling the extra damage dice?

**From the Pathfinder SRD.**

> Vital Strike (Combat)
>
> You make a single attack that deals significantly
>   more damage than normal.
>
> Prerequisites: Base attack bonus +6.
>
> Benefit: When you use the attack
>   action, you can make one attack at
>   your highest base attack bonus that
>   deals additional damage. Roll the
>   weapon’s damage dice for the attack
>   twice and add the results together
>   before adding bonuses from Strength,
>   weapon abilities (such as flaming),
>   precision-based damage, and other
>   damage bonuses. These extra weapon
>   damage dice are not multiplied on a
>   critical hit, but are added to the
>   total.

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/vital-strike-combat---final

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No, you only roll the damage dice of the weapon twice, not any of the modifiers.**

This has been cleared up by Jason, and reproduced on the [d20pfsrd.com FAQ](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/extras/pathfinder-faq#TOC-Vital-Strike-8-20-10-):

> **Q: The text of this feat stipulates
> that the Vital Strike does not
> multiply Strength damage, weapon
> ability damage, or precision damage.
> Are other damage bonuses (those not
> mentioned, such as those from Weapon
> Specialization, enhancement bonuses,
> or the Bard's inspire courage ability)
> are, in fact, multiplied on a hit? I'm
> not sure if that's what is intended,
> though--the wording sounds like it
> could just be saying, "No damage
> bonuses, such as X, Y, and Z, are
> multiplied on a hit. "**
>
> A: (Jason Bulmahn) The way to think
> about it is this: roll the damage dice
> only twice.

And

> **Q: So at 6th level and using a
> longsword +2 and 16 Str and power
> attacking (-2 to hit, +4 damage) using
> the Vital Strike feat would it be 2d8,
> +2 for the sword bonus, +4 for PA, and +3 for Str or 2d8 +4 for the sword bonus, +8 for PA and +3 for Str? And
> then what would the above damage be if
> a critical hit was rolled?**
>
> A: (Jason Bulmahn) The way to think
> about it is this. . roll the damage
> dice only twice. Everything else is as
> per normal. If you crit, add the crit
> damage normally and then roll the base
> dice for the weapon again and add them
> all together. So, in your example, the
> character would roll 1d8+5 attacking
> normally, 1d8+9 if using Power Attack,
> and 2d8+9 if using Power Attack and
> Vital Strike. On a critical hit you
> would roll 3d8+10 if attacking
> normally, 3d8+18 if using Power Attack

One way to think of this is: resolve the attack and damage normally, then add a *weapon-die* worth of damage.